# What is the best way to log Exceptions to a string

Tags: c#, .net

Anyone have a good way to output an Exception in C# to a string that handles inner exceptions and the such?  I am sure every developer has her own implimentation of this, but I can't find my old one and want to see what better ones are out there.

Here is one without recursion for inner exceptions as an example:

```
var Message = String.Format("Exception Message: \n{0}\n\nStackTrace: \n{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply method ToString is the best:

```
ex.ToString();
```

Comment: +1, it's not obvious to a novice as most other framework classes just return the type name in a ToString(), but `Exception.ToString()` has all the information you need.

Comment: +1, and in addition to Matt's comment one should note that *most* (but unfortunately not all) Exceptions write information about auxiliary properties they have into the ToString() output.  If you just use "Message" and "StackTrace" you generally miss out on such properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use string interpolation with the same effect. It improves code readability.

```
Console.WriteLine($"Ex: 1 {ex}");
```

The full example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Foo(); // throws..
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Ex: 1 {ex}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Ex: 2 {ex.ToString()}");
    }
}

private static void Foo()
{
    try { Bar(); }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Bar failed", e);
    }
}

private static void Bar()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Output:

```
Ex: 1 System.Exception: Bar failed
 ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at Program.Bar() in C:\git\src\\Program.cs:line 52
   at Program.Foo() in C:\git\src\\Program.cs:line 42
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Program.Foo() in C:\git\src\\Program.cs:line 46
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\git\src\\Program.cs:line 14
Ex: 2 System.Exception: Bar failed
 ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at Program.Bar() in C:\git\src\\Program.cs:line 52
   at Program.Foo() in C:\git\src\\Program.cs:line 42
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Program.Foo() in C:\git\src\\Program.cs:line 46
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\git\src\\Program.cs:line 14
```